# Flextable export and image width issues

Tags: r, flextable

I am producing some tables which I now wish to incorporate into a latex document (not knitted by R but externally built).

I gather that flextable can now produce latex, but is this ONLY for knitting or can I export it somehow?

Failing that I'm guessing that exporting as an image might be the next best thing?

The tables though are quite wide and I intend to use them in the document rotated (landscape). How do I specify the width of the final image I need, and the DPI I'd like?

Finally, whilst testing all this in an Rmd script, my table columns are getting wrapped as I increase the number of columns.  Is there some way to increase the maximum width available to print?

Updates:

Adding to the .rmd script

`{r plotting fig.width=12, fig.height=8, dev='png'}`

does NOT fix the visible porthole size.

It would appear that when flextable thinks it's running out of room it starts breaking the column contents at spaces, overriding the width() specification.  Replacing the spaces with non-breaking spaces seems to restore some order here.